# Change image SRC when input slider changed

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm have a slider that goes from 1 - 3, I'd like my image src to change depending on what the slider is set to. I've tried to do this using an else if statement but it doesn't seem to be changing?

**HTML**

```
<span id="valBox"></span>
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" step="1">
<img id="demo" src="default-image.png">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    if (step === 1) {
    document.querySelector("input.step").innerHTML.src = "one-image.png";
    } else if (step === 2) {
    document.querySelector("input.step").innerHTML.src = "two-image.png";
    }  else if (step === 3) {
    document.querySelector("input.step").innerHTML.src = "three-image.png";
    };
</script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your JavaScript in an `onchange` event handler.

```js
const imageElement = document.getElementById("demo");
const selectorElement = document.getElementById("selector");
selectorElement.onchange = () => {
  const step = selectorElement.valueAsNumber;  
  if (step === 1) {
      imageElement.src = "one-image.png";
  } else if (step === 2) {
      imageElement.src = "two-image.png";
  }  else if (step === 3) {
      imageElement.src = "three-image.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="valBox"></span>
<input id="selector" type="range" min="1" max="3" step="1">
<img id="demo" src="default-image.png">
```

Comment: Thank-you, that makes sense. I noticed the img src does not change with this. Do I need to add an on-click event to the input ID?

Comment: Hubs you're right. You have to use `valueAsNumber` and not `value` ;)